# Unnecessary ioctl(n, TCGETS) Calls On Socket Handles

Tags: perl, sockets, ioctl

Why does Perl5 implicitly seem to run unnecessary `ioctl()` tty checks against various file handles?

From what I understand, this is a long-standing feature of Perl5 and nobody seems to consider it for change. When I say change, I mean 'implement a change to Perl5 to facilitate the enablement or disablement of such `ioctl()` tty checks' on file handles which you KNOW are NOT tty handles.

I have a TCP/IP socket program and after `accept()` returns on a new socket, the following `strace` shows the `ioctl()`s being called on the new handle. In this context, the `ioctl()` calls are a waste of CPU and load. Of course, if `accept()` and `ioctl()` is called only once, it means nothing much. However, over time, with multiple processes, multiple `ioctl()` calls...it all adds up.

Is there an existing way to explicitly disable such superfluous `ioctl()` tty checks on file handles and sockets etc?

If it cannot be disabled, does anyone think such a contextual ability to disable/enable checks is worthy?

Here is the `strace` excerpt showing a client socket initial connection:

```
18:21:59.818126 select(8, [6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=10, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=9, tv_usec=999997})
18:21:59.818321 accept4(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(56124), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [4096->16], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = 7
18:21:59.818419 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
18:21:59.818453 ioctl(7, TCGETS, 0x7ffff5befcd0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
```

Comment: A [mcve] perl script that demonstrates it would be useful. Not that I think an ioctl makes any difference performance wise. Might as well complain about the unnecessary fcntl too.

Answer (score 2):

So you think there should be a way of telling Perl to check if the handle is a socket to skip executing code that doesn't pertain to sockets.

You shouldn't have to tell Perl to do that; it should be automatic. And it is automatic. The call to `ioctl` is that check.

I think the call in question is from [this sub](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/7b1885ae53fad4123864416d9ef0bbdb78a1882f/perlio.c#L3824) which uses `isatty` to check what kind of buffering should be used. If so, the call to `ioctl` is being used to check if the handle is a socket or not to skip executing code that doesn't pertain to sockets.

Do you have propose there's a better way of checking if a file handle is a socket?

Comment: @zevekz, Re "*is NOT the way to check if a fd is a socket or not.*", The answer doesn't say it is. It checks if it's a socket or other things, or not.

Comment: @zevekz, Re "*And since it's perl itself who called accept(2) or socket(2) that's enough for it to know that the returned fd cannot be a tty.*", `accept` and `socket` know it's not a tty. But that doesn't help at all since it's not `accept` or `socket` doing the check.

Comment: @zevekz, Re "*your last paragraph was probably supposed to be rhetorical*", It was not. If there's a better approach, a ticket could be filed. /// Re "*will tell you if a file descriptor is a socket*", I said a *better* approach. You are reacting as if the OP asked "How does one check if a handle is a socket", but that wasn't asked. The OP wishes to remove the cost of the `ioctl` call, and I doubt that replacing it with a `getsockopt` or `fstat` would achieve that. Specifically, I doubt it provides any benefits for sockets, and it `ioctl` would still need to be called for some non-sockets.

Comment: @zevek. Already said and responded. `accept` and `socket` know it's not a tty. But that doesn't help at all since it's not `accept` or `socket` doing the check. The buffer layer is what needs the info, and it gets it from `ioctl`. See the code I linked above.

Comment: No, it's not, as I said twice already. I even linked to the code that does.

Comment: @zevek. It is done before `socket` returns, but it's not done by `socket`. And it does matter since `socket` knows it's a socket, but the IO buffering layer of the IO library doesn't.

Comment: @zevek. But `socket` doesn't know anything about IO layers. Nor should it. Furthermore, neither the layers mor the IO system need to know about `socket`. And that's how it should be. You're talking about adding a "might be a socket" parameters to a large number of functions and APIs. Just to avoid a call to `ioctl` in some uncommon situations. There's no point to that. You couldn't even use it to tell if it's a socket, only that it might be!

Comment: Sounding like perlio.c buffering is the key area here. 

Historically, I suspect that PerlIO has played a massive part in achieving the outcomes most users have not known they needed -- inherently perl. However, I think perl should mature into a design where historical aspects can be 'turned off'. Maybe ...

 'no feature qw(perlio_isatty)' comes to mind ;) I know that as far as a design choice it would open up a rabbit hole, but wouldn't be the first time the 'feature' mantra has been implemented in patches to facilitate change.

Overriding PerlLIO_isatty() in xs? Can that be done?

Comment: Turning PerlLIO_isatty() into a no-op... Sounds stupid. I agree. But in an explicit context, not so much. Maybe overriding PerlIOBuf_pushed() is the answer. Maybe even perl 'gears', where subsets of features are turned on or off via overrides to cater for a specific load / application setting.